# Determine which UIButton is pressed without using tag or name attribute

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have multiple buttons which are created programmatically when the users want to create a new button. The button can be edited and to work out which one is pressed I use the `UIButton`'s `tag` property which is then passed through a dictionary if the tag value matches one stored.

I know I could also work out which button is pressed by using the button name but there might be duplicate button names.

Is there any other way? I am just wondering if I am doing this the best way using the `UIButton`'s `tag`. I do create UUID when each button is created. Could this be used somehow?

Comment: You could just put a reference to the `UIButton` itself in an array or dictionary - What do you need to do once you have identified the button?

Comment: Do each of the button's provide the same functionality,  i.e. connected to the same action when pressed? Why don't you want to use the tag feature?

Comment: The buttons can have their own actions and be connected to other buttons using a drag line like in xcode.

Comment: Paulw11 - What about creating  a custom uibutton class like class CustomBtn: UIButton {
    var UUIDtag: UUID?
}

Comment: What do you mean, the buttons are connected to other buttons? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry it gets a bit confusing as I can't really show the project. A button when pressed can highlight another button which in turn for example start a timer or countdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paulw11 gave me an idea of simply creating a custom UIbutton. When creating the button, instead of using UIButton, I use CustomBtn.

When a button is created, a UUID is assigned to the customBtn.UUID which is then saved to my database. I then use a filter to compared the CustomBtn.UUIDtag to the ones saved when I click a button. This bypass having to use the UIbutton.tag if needed.

```
@IBAction func mainButton(sender: CustomBtn){
if let button = buttonPlist.arrayObjects.filter({$0.UUIDbtn == sender.UUIDtag}).first {

//ACTION to be implemented
  }
}

class CustomBtn: UIButton {
var UUIDtag: UUID?
}
```

Comment: I am creating buttons and sub-buttons which means using button.tag can cause the same tag to be use twice unless i set the sub-button start value of the tag  to 500 for example. This in my opinion gets messy. If I use the UUID they all have their individual value. This is why I was trying to find a way not to use tag. I hope this makes sense.